# How to use CASE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have

```
SET @q=10;
SET @p=5.00;
UPDATE 1detail SET quantity =
               CASE 
               WHEN @q=<quantity THEN (quantity - @q) AND SET @q=0
               WHEN @q > quantity THEN 0 AND SET @q=(@q-quantity); 
               END
            WHERE price>=@p ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is it possible to redefine the variable in this CASE statement in MySQL? How can I do that if possible.

The statement returns:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=
>
> ```
>                WHEN @q > quantity THEN 0 A' at line 3
> ```

Comment: You can't use SET command on the case statement.

Comment: just updated my answer, it should work, have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=< is not valid, use <= instead

try the following SQL, it seems like you are okay with multiple statment so I made it 2 parts. Might not look good(cause I'm not a SQL pro)  but it should work.

```
SET @q=10;
SET @p=5.00;
update 1detail 
SET quantity = 
if((@q := quantity - @q) >= 0, @q, 0)
WHERE price>=@p ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;

SET @q = if(@q <0,@q-@q-@q, @q);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Should use case when defining another set in update query.

```
SET @q=10;
SET @p=5.00;
UPDATE 1detail SET quantity =
           CASE 
           WHEN @q=<quantity THEN (quantity - @q) AND SET @q=0
           case
           WHEN @q > quantity THEN 0 AND SET @q=(@q-quantity); 
           END
        WHERE price>=@p ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Returns a similar error message: " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=<quantity THEN (quantity - @q) AND SET @q=0
           case
           WHEN @' at line 3"

Comment: Its because you can only update table column values using set . Not local values like @q . I